# searchBarTextDidBeginEditing not being called when i use it in navigation controller Swift 3.

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I have searched for hours trying to solve my problem, but i could not find any solutions.

My problem is that i have a SearchBar inside my navigation bar. I did setup my SearchBar like this:

```
lazy var searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect.zero)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchBar.delegate = self
        searchBar.placeholder = "Search"

        navigationItem.titleView = searchBar

    }
```

When i try to call for example a function from the protocol UISearchBarDelegate it won't respond. 
The function is for example:

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        print("Did run")
    }
```

This function does not execute. How would i make functions from UISearchBarDelegate execute programmatically inside a navigation bar? The reason for that i do this programmatically is because i use the search bar inside a navigation bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your delegate function is just a bit different from the right one, at the parameter. It should be:

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
  //code
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, what is the difference between this function and my function?

Comment: The parameter of the delegate starts with a _, and yours didn't. You can see the warning of the "nearly matches optional requirement", and that means: "I think you want this function, but you typed it just a little bit different"

Comment: Yes i have to wait in 5 minutes